Cant modify cells in an Excel Python Dataframe - Dataframe displays None
I am new to Python in Excel 365 and a somewhat new with Python language in general.
I cant seem to copy the contents of a dataframe to another dataframe on the same worksheet.
for example, the following python code does not write the value of the cell in dataframe 'df' to dataframe 'df1'. Dataframe df displays 'None'.
#Read 'df' cell value  your text`temp = df.loc[0,'Ticker']
your text#Copy 'df' cell value to 'df1'
your textdf1.loc[0,'Ticker'] = temp
your text#NOTE: This does not seem to work. df1 displays "None" for all cells `
Tried accessing dataframes with loc and iloc methods. I can copy the desired dataframe cell value to a variable with these methods. I cant copy a cell directly to another dataframe.
